# Recover root password on debian

Tags: debian, password-recovery

I lost root password for **Debian server**.
it's runing very important services like radius server and wifi controller
How I can recover password without lose data?

Comment: Reset the password (need restart/downtime). Or try to use `sudo` if configured.

Answer (score 2):

If the boot loader isn't locked you can hit `e` to edit the entry and append `init=/bin/sh` to the kernel line, herewith an example:
[GRUB boot loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE7gl.png)

ie: Append  `init=/bin/sh` to the end of the linux line (most probably multiple lines)

You should then land on a '# ' prompt but be aware that the root filesystem will be mounted read-only (if you run 'mount' it will say something like '/dev/sda3 on / type xfs (ro,' (ro = read only).

Remount the file system in read write mode by entering: `mount -o remount,rw /`

Unlock the 'root' account: `passwd -u root`
Change the 'root' account password: `passwd root`
Flush pending writes: `sync`
Remount the file system in read only mode again: `mount -o remount,ro /`
Exit the shell: `exit`

The system will then show a kernel panic, as 'init' just exited. Simply reset and then login with your reset credentials.

Comment: Great answer. really was it.  Althougth the hard disk was damaged and this huge bug was the problem main